# An exception in MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()

Tags: java, swing, javafx, nullpointerexception, mouse-cursor

I Use JavaFX and Swing in my GUI app.
More detailed, I use SwingNode on top of AnchorPane to add a JPanel, and some map on it (ARCGIS JMap - that runs only on swing), that refreshes itself all the time.

When I drag my app between two display screens, sometime I have a `NullPointerException`.

This is the java code where it happens:

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

The drag is performed on JavaFX element (the event is JavaFX event):

```
    private void setDraggable(Parent root) {
    if (root != null) {
        root.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
            xOffset = mainStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            yOffset = mainStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged((event) -> {
            mainStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
            mainStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
        });
    }
```

But the exception happens on AWT thread.
As I said, the code where it falls is (please note that this is internal java code, not mine):

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

What can I do to prevent this?

And another question, that maybe will give a clue - I checked, and both my only Swing components (JPanel and JMap) are children of JComponent. But the exception occurs in JLightweightFrame. So how can it be possible?

Here is the full trace of the exception:

```
Message = Thread AWT-EventQueue-0 (Id = 45) throw exception: null Stack-Trace = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.swing.JLightweightFrame.updateClientCursor(JLightweightFrame.java:473)
    at sun.swing.JLightweightFrame.access$000(JLightweightFrame.java:79)
    at sun.swing.JLightweightFrame$1.updateCursor(JLightweightFrame.java:112)
    at sun.awt.windows.WLightweightFramePeer.updateCursorImmediately(WLightweightFramePeer.java:92)
    at java.awt.Component.updateCursorImmediately(Component.java:3150)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1642)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2748)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: How you combine Swing with JavaFX?What swing componexts you mix with FX .They are running in different Threads.Although where are you calling the `MouseInfo` code?More information is needed...;)

Comment: Sure. I use SwingNode on top of AnchorPane to add a JPanel, and some map on it (ARCGIS JMap - that runs only on swing), that refreshes itself all the time.About the MouseInfo - I don't call it. No code of mine on the stacktrace. The app does it itself.

Comment: This is going to be almost impossible to answer without a [mcve]. Start a new project and add a `SwingNode` to the JavaFX application without the `JMap`. Then see if the problem occurs and if not start adding to it the code you had until you get the exception. When you found what's causing it post that program.

Comment: copied from the deleted answer to not loose it: can be https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6840067

Comment: The more specific bug seems to be this one:  https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8185890